# Is this site ready to leave private beta?

Tags: discussion

Are we sure this site is ready to leave private beta?

Yes there will be an influx of new blood and that will help the site develop, but have we properly defined this site and the types of questions that should be kept here and not closed/migrated?

Are you happy with the site the way it is forming?

Answer (score 3):

No, we are not ready to leave private beta. There's no consensus on what level of questions are good one. Maybe "extending" the private beta's membership is one option, but opening it up will lock our current state in.

Comment: I have no idea what Jeff and the team are willing to do here, but I figure this question gives us an option for some input and discussion to give to the SOIS team. I have a feeling they'll say proceed with the public beta and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cite *metrics* if you feel the site isn't ready to leave private beta.

During the private beta ...

- how many users participated?
- how many questions?
- how many answers?
- how much rep did users generate?

These are the facts of the situation.

Comment: I wouldn't know the answers to those compared to others to say for sure. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

Have we properly defined the site?  **No.**

Are we supposed to do that in the private or public beta?  I have no idea.

I'd say that the change from 'Database Professionals' to 'Database Administrators' caused the problem -- they have siginificantly different boundaries, and people signed up for something that's not what the site opened as.

I'd personally like to throw it open to the rest of the public to see what their opinion in the scope of the site should be, but it's possible that we might end up self-selecting by advertising as 'Database Administrators' and not get as diverse of a population, and so taint the surveying of what's on/off topic.

Comment: Indeed. I feel I agree with everything you're saying here. I too am ready for the influx of new blood in about an hour, and I've got several people I'm going to suggest the site to right away. That being said, I'm still not sure this site is going to take off. My fear is that of hitting the same fate as the AI group http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/

Answer (score 1):

Is this really a question ?

For me it reads like:
Oh Jeff we are weak. 
We didn't succeed in qualifying enough high rep users, please give us some more time.

I think there are people outside the private beta wanting to start it today as planned.

I don't think, that Jeff will change the procedure.

Comment: oh dear, I see my iPhone didn't quite convey what I was trying to post there :| ... I see my question as part question, part peptalk, and as a point of question for us as a group.