# How long is the beta period and when is it finished?

Tags: discussion

The area51 Faq at http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq (which I believe to be relevant for dba.stackexchange.com) states that a "site is launched for a beta period to seed it with questions, develop the FAQ, appoint temporary moderators, and refine its design."

I was wondering how it is determined how long this period lasts, and how far we are from the end of it.

On a related note: [Is this site ready to leave private beta?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111/is-this-site-ready-to-leave-private-beta) meantions a *private* beta. Is the *private* beta just the same as the beta, or is there something like a *public* beta (and which one would this site be in?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The private beta is 7 days.

The public beta goes for 90 days, but may be extended if the site still needs some time to develop.

If you go to the [DBA Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators) on Area 51, it will show you the current status of the site and number of days remaining in the current phase.
[image: Area 51 screenshot]

And finally, Robert answers all your questions better than I ever could in his [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) blog post.

Comment: I hope this site gets out of beta and goes fully public. It is definitely a bold and brash forum for Database people !!!