# Are we ready to leave public beta and launch?

Tags: discussion, beta

The [stats on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators) show the site is now going well. It is not good to [launch too soon](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/how-long-is-the-beta-period-and-when-is-it-finished), but I imagine that some potential users are put off by the 'beta' tag and the site will grow more quickly after we launch

I understand there [is a queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73557/why-still-in-public-beta-area-51/73562#73562) once a site is ready to launch - I'd be interested to know whether we are in that queue yet, and if so, how many sites are ahead of us

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is not official sanction**, but I know (via brief twitter conversation) that the designer Jin has been working on a new theme for the site. It normally takes him a month or so to get that in order, between the conceptual design and the actual layout and such, but the **point is this**: They don't start a design until the site is about ready to launch.

So, I think we are.

Comment: Nice. Do we get input on the theme? Not that I have an artistic bone in my body mind :)

Comment: Once Jin posts something on this meta, yes.

Comment: Will we keep the same name? I see 'outerjoin' [was suggested](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260?phase=commitment) way back when the site was proposed, which I think would suit us pretty well.

Comment: I like that, but does it imply only databases? I'll bump one of the Qs here on meta. We need to start putting up a list of names now.

Answer (score 6):

@jcolebrand's answer is, essentially, correct. Jin, [our designer in residence](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/), is slated to be working on the Database Administrators SE shortly, so you should be seeing a first draft of your new design soon. Congratulations!

I recently submitted a blog post covering the days leading up to graduation.

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)